# is there a way to control the size of rectangle in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

am using this code to draw rectangle in my **image**,

```
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image=pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_folder,"Player.png"))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.vel_x = 0
    self.speed = 30
    self.friction = 3.5
    self.rect.center = (420,360)
    self.delta = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.00
```

but the method **get_rect()** is drawing the rectangle on the entire loaded  image like this
[image]

and i want it to be like this 
[image]

Comment: Can you link where you draw the rect? I'm assuming you're using the rect you get off the image

Comment: **image.get_rect()** get the size of the loaded image then draws a rectangle around it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a rectangle where you know the hull will be, if the hull will be in the same place and the same size every time

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect(hulltop,hullleft,hullwidth,hullheight)
```

In your case `hullwidth` might be the image width and `hullheight` looks like your image height minus `hulltop`.

If you have different hulls, you might consider having the hull and the mast/sail in separate image files, creating your outline of just the hull, then joining the images. Alternatively you could create a dict of the different hull sizes and use that to determine the size and position of the rectangle to draw.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the `Rect` of the image. If you want to have a differently sized `Rect`, you're going to need to create one.